# How to join characters _vertically_?

Tags: vertical-spacing

I want to show the way to draw certain consonant-consonant combined forms in the devanaagarii script. To illustrate that, I want to *vertically* combine the letters (`c` is used as a placeholder) and place a `\downarrow` such that the assembly look like this:

[image]

How may I achieve this? (Note, I use `\makebox[0pt]{...}` for horizontal merging of characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a `\Shortstack` for the `ccc` with 0pt stacking gap, and I use `scalerel` to make the arrow match the vertical footprint of the c-stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\mystack[2]{\scaleleftright{.}{\Shortstack{#1}}{#2}}
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\mystack{c c c}{\downarrow} xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]